# Perl: matching strings containing slash in quotation marks

Tags: regex, perl

I'm currently writing a Perl script to parse a config file. The syntax is as follows

```
{command parameter1 parameter2}
```

where the second parameter is optional. In the first place I just want to extract the content between `{` and `}`. Im using this code

```
while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;
    unless ($_ =~ m/^\/\//) {
            $_ =~ /^\{(.*?)\}/s;
            print $1;
}
```

Instead of the `print` command the string will be evaluated further. My problem now is that the script just stops working with some strings

The script works, as long there are quotation marks around the arguments. This

```
{exec sed 's/ClientAliveInterval\ 300/ClientAliveInterval\ 1800/\' /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /etc/ssh/sshd_config.new}
```

will return the content between the brackets, but since there could be a second parameter it is now hard to distinguish the parameters without qoutation marks

Other strings like

```
{exec "cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.bak"}
{exec "/etc/init.d/ssh reload"}
```

work perfectly, including the quotation marks.

But now, strings in quotation marks including a slash or a plus sign (maybe also others) just freeze the perl script at this point:

```
{exec "chmod +x /root/setSSHTimer.sh"}
{exec "sed 's/ClientAliveInterval\ 300/ClientAliveInterval\ 1800/\' /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /etc/ssh/sshd_config.new"}
```

Both with quotation marks. When rewriting the first to "chmod 770..." it works again.

Any ideas what causes the problem here?

Comment: I'd honestly suggest a more robust configuration setting such as JSON or XML.

Comment: As Jack says, if you are having trouble parsing your own design for a config syntax then something has gone badly wrong. The file can look however you want it to, and the problem you are having could be fixed by having the command and parameters on separate lines with, say, a blank line to separate them. Have you accounted for the parameters containing `{}` characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't in the code you've shown, which just extracts everything between the `{...}` braces, but in the *evaluated further* code. Please publish this if you are having problems with it

Note that you can avoid escaping slashes in a regex simply by using a different delimiter, and a line like `next if m|^//|` avoids putting all of the rest of the loop within an `if` statement

Parsing a command line is awkward - because you have to cope with parameters contained within both `"..."` and `'...'` quotes, allowing for escaped quotes within the parameter - but possible

Here is a program that seems to parse all of your example data properly

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {

  next if m|^//| or not /\S/;

  if (/^\{(.*?)\}/) {
    my $command = $1;
    my @fields = $command =~ /'(?:\\'|[^'])*'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*"|\S+/g;
    print join(' ', map "[$_]", @fields), "\n";
  }
}

__DATA__
{exec sed 's/ClientAliveInterval\ 300/ClientAliveInterval\ 1800/\' /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /etc/ssh/sshd_config.new'}
{exec "cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.bak"}
{exec "/etc/init.d/ssh reload"}
{exec "chmod +x /root/setSSHTimer.sh"}
{exec "sed 's/ClientAliveInterval\ 300/ClientAliveInterval\ 1800/\' /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /etc/ssh/sshd_config.new"}
```

**output**

```
[exec] [sed] ['s/ClientAliveInterval\ 300/ClientAliveInterval\ 1800/\' /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /etc/ssh/sshd_config.new']
[exec] ["cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.bak"]
[exec] ["/etc/init.d/ssh reload"]
[exec] ["chmod +x /root/setSSHTimer.sh"]
[exec] ["sed 's/ClientAliveInterval\ 300/ClientAliveInterval\ 1800/\' /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /etc/ssh/sshd_config.new"]
```

---

**Update**

This config format should at least be split over lines so that the quotes and escapes can be removed, for instance

```
exec
sed
s/ClientAliveInterval\ 300/ClientAliveInterval\ 1800/ /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /etc/ssh/sshd_config.new

exec
cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.bak

exec
/etc/init.d/ssh reload

exec
chmod +x /root/setSSHTimer.sh

exec
sed
s/ClientAliveInterval\ 300/ClientAliveInterval\ 1800/\' /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /etc/ssh/sshd_config.new
```

which is very easy both to enter correctly and to parse (although I am sure that your final `sed` example is wrong!)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your perfect answer! From there i was able to integrate it in my script and parse everything successfully. Thanks! Unfortunatly i cannot indicate your answer as "useful"...

Comment: Please bear in mind my comment on your question. This is a poor design for a config syntax

Comment: Borodin: thanks for your feedback, i know that the design is far away from being perfect. It is a small script for internal (seldom) usage. it is sufficient for what we are going to do with it, and i will never release it to the public, there some more security "features" ;) But again - thanks for your help!

Comment: All I mean is that you are making things hard for yourself. The config *will* get more complicated, I promise you, and the current design barely copes with the requirement

Comment: @waza-ari: I strongly agree with Borodin here. You really should give it a rethink. It's like getting teeth pulled-- painful initially, but you'll feel better later, and if you don't get the tooth pulled it will just build up pressure and pain over time.

Comment: @Borodin: Thanks for your Update. The sed example is wrong, there is a backslash too much in there... recognized it myself.  But thanks for the hint. At All: I know there are some classes which can parse other formatted config files. Could you then suggest a module which can be used for this kind of job? Thanks in advance